# Texture rendering as black in one spot only?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I have a render and from a specific angle at specific distance my timber material renders out as black. I have adjusted the render passes and that doesn't seem to be it. If i move the camera the location changes but I cannot figure out which setting is causing the issue.

[image: Black Texture]

Does anyone have any ideas how to fix it?

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue - I had the normals set up wrong in my shader. It only showed up from that particular angle - every other angle seemed to render just fine.